# When I kill the app, the service is destroyed as well?

Tags: android, service

When the app is swiped from the list of recent applications, is the services from the app also stopped? Or, they keep alive?

> START_STICKY
>
> If the system kills the service after onStartCommand()
> returns, recreate the service and call onStartCommand() but do not
> redeliver the last intent. Instead, the system calls onStartCommand()
> with a null intent unless there are pending intents to start the
> service. In that case, those intents are delivered. This is suitable
> for media players (or similar services) that are not executing
> commands but are running indefinitely and waiting for a job.

I know that there is an option of returning START_STICKY on the `onStartCommand` of the Service. But, wouldn't the service be killed when I kill the app? And, will it be returned/restarted?

So, that means that if I return `START_STICKY`  the service will keep running indefinitely until I intentionally stop it?

```
 @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
      // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job
      Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
      msg.arg1 = startId;
      mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

      // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
      return START_STICKY;
  }
```

Comment: short answer: it will restart

Comment: @user1506104 even for Android 8/8.1 where they have limitations for background applications? Do not they go to kill the service permanently?